# PostGIS: parse geometry wkb with OGR

Tags: python, postgis, ogr, well-known-binary, psycopg2

I'm trying to pull a `LineString` geometry out of PostGIS and parse it with OGR (python bindinds).

```
from osgeo import ogr
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect("...")
cursor = connection.cursor()

query = "SELECT geom FROM points LIMIT 1"

cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchone()

wkb = row[0]
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(wkb)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

I've tried:

```
wkb = bin(int(row[0], 16))
```

and:

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKB(geom) FROM points LIMIT 1
```

OGR does not want to parse it. Keeps giving the following error:

```
ERROR 3: OGR Error: Unsupported geometry type
```

Comment: Mistype on this line; make sure it is not in your code: `geom = org.CreateGeometryFromWkb(wkb)` (should be `ogr` not `org`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Internally, PostGIS stores geometries in a binary specification, but it is queried and viewed outside as a hex-encoded string. There are two popular variations of [well-known binary (WKB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_binary):

- **EWKB** (via **`ST_AsEWKB`**) - an extended WKB specification [designed by PostGIS](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/browser/trunk/doc/ZMSgeoms.txt).
- **OGC WKB** (via **`ST_AsBinary`**) - specified by the OGC and ISO. For a while it was 2D-only, but later extended to support `Z`, `M` and `ZM` geometries.

The two specifications are the same for 2D geometries, but are different for higher-order geometries with `Z`, `M` and `ZM` coordinates.

---

**Older versions of GDAL/OGR (1.x)** only understand the EWKB for 3D geometries, so for these I recommend using `ST_AsEWKB`. (But if you only have 2D geometries, either format are fine). For example:

```
import psycopg2
from osgeo import ogr

ogr.UseExceptions()    
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=postgis user=postgres')
curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute("select ST_AsEWKB('POINT Z (1 2 3)'::geometry) AS g")
b = bytes(curs.fetchone()[0])
print(b.encode('hex'))  # 0101000080000000000000f03f00000000000000400000000000000840
g = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(b)
print(g.ExportToWkt())  # POINT (1 2 3)

curs.execute("select ST_AsBinary('POINT Z (1 2 3)'::geometry) AS g")
b = bytes(curs.fetchone()[0])
print(b.encode('hex'))  # 01e9030000000000000000f03f00000000000000400000000000000840
g = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(b)
# RuntimeError: OGR Error: Unsupported geometry type
```

Also, note that older GDAL/OGR versions do not support `M` coordinates, and these will be parsed but ignored.

---

**With GDAL 2.0 and more recent**, [ISO WKT/WKB is supported](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc49_curve_geometries). This means that `CreateGeometryFromWkb` can read either WKB flavour (without specifying) and `ExportToIsoWkt()` shows output with a modern WKT syntax.

```
import psycopg2
from osgeo import ogr

ogr.UseExceptions()
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=postgis user=postgres')
curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute("select ST_AsEWKB('POINT Z (1 2 3)'::geometry) AS g")
b = bytes(curs.fetchone()[0])
print(b.encode('hex'))  # 0101000080000000000000f03f00000000000000400000000000000840
g = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(b)
print(g.ExportToIsoWkt())  # POINT Z (1 2 3)

curs.execute("select ST_AsBinary('POINT Z (1 2 3)'::geometry) AS g")
b = bytes(curs.fetchone()[0])
print(b.encode('hex'))  # 01e9030000000000000000f03f00000000000000400000000000000840
g = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(b)
print(g.ExportToIsoWkt())  # POINT Z (1 2 3)
```

Additionally, GDAL 2.1 or later will create/export WKT/WKB with `M` or `ZM` coordinates as expected.

Comment: For me it is the other way around. With ST_AsEWKB I get ERROR 3: OGR Error: Unsupported geometry type. But with ST_AsBinary it reads fine: MULTILINESTRING ((-4.625433 40.682732,-4.6275242 40.6820109,-4.6293233 40.681392,-4.6301239 40.681117))

Answer (score 9):

> Within the database, geometries are stored on disk in a format only used by the PostGIS program. In order for external programs to insert and retrieve useful geometries, they need to be converted into a format that other applications can understand. Fortunately, PostGIS supports emitting and consuming geometries in a large number of formats:

from [Introduction to PostGIS](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geometries.html)

With the WKB format:

> Well-known binary (WKB):
>       ST_GeomFromWKB(bytea) returns geometry
>       ST_AsBinary(geometry) returns bytea
>       ST_AsEWKB(geometry) returns bytea

ogr recognize geometries an not a bytea result (`ST_AsEWKB()`)

```
# result -> bytea format:
query = "SELECT ST_AsEWKB(geom) FROM points LIMIT 1"
# result -> geometry from bytea:
query = "SELECT ST_GeomFromWKB(ST_AsEWKB(geom)) from points LIMIT 1;"
```

Test with one of my tables:

nothing:

```
query = """SELECT ST_AsText(ST_AsEWKB(geom)) from mytable;"""
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
row = cur.fetchone()
print row[0]
'01010000208A7A0000DD2571661A9B10410CCD751AEBF70241'
```

and a geometry:

```
query = """SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromWKB(ST_AsEWKB(geom))) from mytable;"""
# result
cur.execute(query)
row = cur.fetchone()
print row
('POINT(272070.600041 155389.38792)',)
```

So, let's try:

```
 query = """SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromWKB(ST_AsEWKB(geom))) from mytable;"""
 cur = conn.cursor()
 cur.execute(query)
 row = cur.fetchone()    
 wkb = row[0];
 geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(wkb)
 ERROR 3: OGR Error: Unsupported geometry type
```

Why ?

Because the result of the query is a string:

```
'01010000208A7A0000DD2571661A9B10410CCD751AEBF70241'
```

and not a bytecode.

You need to decode this string (look at Create Geometry from WKB in the [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html) ).

That is why it is much easier to use:

1) other output formats (WKT, GeoJSON, ...)

```
 query = """SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) from mytable;"""  
 cur.execute(query)
 row = cur.fetchone()
 point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromJson(row[0])
 print "%d,%d" % (point.GetX(), point.GetY())
 272070,155389
```

2) directly osgeo.ogr ([How to convert PostGIS table to Shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16737/how-to-convert-postgis-table-to-shapefile-in-python), for example)

Comment: +1 for the ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) solution.

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to use `ST_AsBinary(geom)` to convert your geometry from the PostGIS internal format to WKB that you can read with ogr:

```
cur.execute('SELECT ST_AsBinary(geom) FROM mytable LIMIT 1')
result = cur.fetchone()
```

In Postgres terms, your result is a `bytea`.  The psycpopg2 library will map this to a `memoryview` Python type:

```
>>>> type(result[0])
<class 'memoryview'>
```

Just cast your `memoryview` to `bytes` to read the WKB with ogr:

```
>>>>geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(bytes(result[0]))
<osgeo.ogr.Geometry; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRGeometryShadow *' at 0x0000000002D179F0> >
```

If you're concerned with numerical precision, definitely avoid using `ST_AsText()`.  That function converts your geometry to WKT, truncating your coordinates at a precision that depends on your PostGIS version and platform.