# coordinates point in any reference system

Tags: postgresql, mapfile

I have a coordinates point like this "01010000003413056727B71D41C7F1A68B1ADC4141", but I don't know it is what.

Can you aswer What is this?

Answer (score 3):

This is WKB (Well known binary). You can read the definition here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary

For use in Postgis, see [PostGIS: parse geometry wkb with OGR](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89323/postgis-parse-geometry-wkb-with-ogr)